# How to get data from wordpress and show in kivymd?

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I want to fetch and show post data on my kivymd app from wordpress blog:

Here is blog : [Binghow.com](https://binghow.com/)

When i try to run this code, it shows data in the console, what I want is to show my data in kivymd app.

Note: I am new in programming and trying KivyMD

```
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import Label
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (350, 600)


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        
        label = Label(text="Kisan Mitra", color="red", font_size="40px", pos_hint={
                      "center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.6})
        
        screen.add_widget(label)
               
        return screen

    def got_json(req, result):
        for key, value in req.resp_headers.items():
         print('{}: {}'.format(key, value))
    req = UrlRequest("https://binghow.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts", got_json)


MyApp().run()
```